# How to adjust "requirements.txt" to get Python inserting data to ES?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to sent data to Elastic Search using Python and Im getting error: ElasticHttpError: 406, Elastic Search Error While indexing Data

After some googling I found that I need to specify ES version in "requirements.txt" but I havent found this file. Can anybody help what to do? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use this page for help: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py

Look under the compatability section..

A direct look of this section:
The recommended way to set your requirements in your setup.py or requirements.txt is:

The recommended way to set your requirements in your setup.py or requirements.txt is:

```
# Elasticsearch 6.x
elasticsearch>=6.0.0,<7.0.0

# Elasticsearch 5.x
elasticsearch>=5.0.0,<6.0.0

# Elasticsearch 2.x
elasticsearch>=2.0.0,<3.0.0
```

Seems like you must make the file yourself and add the setting/configuration..

Hope this helps!

As far as what to do after that, Im sad to say I have no ideas. But thats how the Requirements.txt should be made(Ill see about a specific directory or if you have to write it into your script)